# The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Key'.... I am using Flutter

Tags: flutter

Does anyone can help my problem ?

I have a Flutter script below :

```
            ListTile(
              title: const Text("Change Password"),
              trailing: const Icon(Icons.lock),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ChangePassword(
                          value: value, key: null,
                        )));
              },
            ),
```

that script is calling the routine below :

```
class ChangePassword extends StatefulWidget {
  List value;
  ChangePassword({required Key key, required this.value}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<ChangePassword> createState() => _ChangePasswordState();
}
```

And i've got an error message :
"The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Key'"

how do i solve my problem ? I don't have any idea....

Thanks in advance,
Tono.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here.

1. Since you are passing an empty key anyway, just update your code like:

```
class ChangePassword extends StatefulWidget {
  final List value;
  const ChangePassword({required this.value, super.key,});
  @override
  State<ChangePassword> createState() => _ChangePasswordState();
}
```

2. If you need the Key definitely, you can do something like this (I am updating also your code, so you will dont get any "problems"):

```
class ChangePassword extends StatefulWidget {
  final List value;
  const ChangePassword({required this.value, Key? key}): super(key: key);
  @override
  State<ChangePassword> createState() => _ChangePasswordState();
}
```

I recommend to use the first one. And I think you have deleted the "?" after key by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the key parameter is nullable, like this:

`class ChangePassword extends StatefulWidget { List value; ChangePassword({Key? key, required this.value}) : super(key: key);`

Answer (score 0):

just set your key like this **key:Key('')**

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) => ChangePassword( value: value, key:Key(""), ))); }, ),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change its type to Key?, which allows null values. Update the constructor to handle the nullable key.

```
class ChangePassword extends StatefulWidget {
  List value;
  ChangePassword({Key? key, required this.value}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<ChangePassword> createState() => _ChangePasswordState();
}
```